# Convert string to a formatted date in Android

Tags: java, android

In my Java Cloud Endpoints API I have some code to get the current date and then store that date in my Cloud SQL (MySQL) database:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
//formattedDate is then inserted into the database
```

Later on in my Android Activity I query the database and get the date back as a String that looks like:

```
2015-06-24 17:53:01
```

Now I want to format this date to display it like `06/24/2015` on the UI of my Activity. To accomplish this I do the following:

```
//I get a string like 2015-06-24 17:53:01 passed in from another activity
//which in-turn got it from the MySQL database
datetime = getIntent().getExtras().getString("datetime");

//first convert the string datatime to a date object
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//then format that date object the way you want
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(convertedDate);

//set the TextView in my Activity to display 06/24/2015
myDateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
```

This works. But man is it a convoluted way to do something simple. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: For the answers people are giving, can you also show how to get the string the way I want it (e.g. 6/25/2015) in the final activity?

Comment: MySQL has [date-time data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html). Why do you not use them?

Comment: @BasilBourque I use the 'datetime' datatype in my MySQL database. Is that OK?

Comment: If using date-time data type, then use date-time objects on the Java side. Don't do all that String converting. Java includes the java.sql.Timestamp/.Date/.Time for this purpose (not to be confused with java.util.Date, util vs sql). Add Joda-Time and you are good to go. This Question is a duplicate of many many others already posted in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save long value represented date into DB.

```
long l = c.getTimeInMillis()
```

and this value you should save.

answer on your question below:

```
    Date date=new Date(l);
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String dateText = df2.format(date);
    System.out.println(dateText);
```

Comment: How do I then get the date in a string the way I want it (e.g. 6/25/2015) in my activity?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in general, whenever I am using dates in my Android App and Database, I should just use the Long datatype?

Comment: yes, you should. The long representation will address less space and in case if indexing also.

Comment: Do you know off the top of your head if I store a Long in the MySQL database will it show a Long string or an actual date when I go to phpmyadmin and view the row?

Comment: long (number) not string. You should use long always, not only in Android App, also for php... you can convert from long to date in php also...

Comment: I just think it is confusing if you go to phpmyadmin and it shows a bunch of numbers instead of the date in the date column - but I guess if that is the way to do it, that is the way to do it.

Comment: What datatype do you use for the date in the MySQL database though? Int?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to store date in **long value** at DB, after that you can format to string in a very simple way.

```
DateFormat.format("MMM dd, yyyy", milliseconds).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the source code of insertion into database, try inserting the timestamp in Long. Then conversion of timestamp to date format should be straight forward.

in Android,

`final String data = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy",timestamp);`